# Document Recovery

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I am creating an automation solution for Word (2007). Sometimes I have to kill the Word process. Next time word is launched a tab/window appears suggesting to recover an unsaved document. I would like to either disable this or have my application close this window.
I have no idea where the entry point to this tab/window is.

EDIT: I've found out that word calls this "Feature" Repair, not Recover. Still no idea how to avoid/bypass/disable it.

Suggestions?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.  It is not programming related.

Comment: yeah well, how to disable it? there also should be a way to close that tab programaticly

Comment: I have the same problem. It's sad that this is not possible within Word, but I have still hope to disable it (clear cache or something else) outside the Word. Anyway, good question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible atm. Maybe on next SP...

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by deleting the Resiliency key in the Registry before starting Word again. This is described here:

> [Every other time that you open a document in Word, the document opens in recovery mode or you receive an error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885380)

You can safely delete the entire Resilience key for local machine and the current user. Note that there are various places where the key is stored:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Word\Resiliency
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Word\Resiliency
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Word\Resiliency

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have access to the word:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6012331_disable-document-recovery-word.html

[edit]

Seems this doesn't work, you could try 
Options.SaveInterval = 0

(source: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Word/microsoft.public.word.customization.menustoolbars/2004-07/0195.html)

but I assume this gives the same effect as what I said first.

[/edit]

Comment: no, this is NOT the document recoery, this is the auto recovery (auto saving document every x mins). Those are completle different points.

Comment: Disabling the automatic save of the document removed the automatic recovery of the file. If the document doesn't get saved as a temp file every x minutes, it doesn't exist when restarted word and thus wont raise the document recovery window

Comment: Nope, word still saves recovery informations for crash purpose. Just give it a try (use 2007!): open a file and modify it while the auto recovery is disabled. Use the taskmanager to kill word and reopen the file. You will get the recover tab...

Comment: If so, I believe there is not way to disable it. Perhaps you can find a way to close the window in my second link (tech-archive) but I lightly doubt it.