# MS Word 2010 - How to programatically clear the "Document Recovery"

Tags: .net, powershell, word-2010

According to this StackOverflow question ([Document Recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757582/document-recovery)), it's not possible to turn off the "Document Recovery" in MS Word 2010. From time to time I need to kill some winword processes which are stored in this "Document Recovery" and when there are tens or hundreds of them, application stops to generate Word documents and I need to manually open Word document and click "Close" in the "Document Recovery".

So, is it possible to automatically clear the "Document Recovery" in MS Word 2010? How to access it with Powershell or .Net?

Comment: Should be able to just delete all files in the application data\word directory with the .asd extension...

Comment: Hi Cole, great idea. I was looking for some recovery files in the same directory where the original files was stored, but found none. I'll check it tomorrow and post reply. Thank you

Comment: I went ahead and tested it for you, it doesn't work. You can remove the file but it still pops up the recovery window, and when you click a file it then realizes it's not there. It is probably built into the code, because I cannot see any temporary data for it. Is there anyway to avoid this patch altogether by just facing the problem at hand: how your closing winword programmatically. There are ways, especially in powershell, to close a document without crashing the program. Post the code that is causing this problem please

Comment: aaaaa, I just arrived at work to test it. It's sad that it doesn't work. For the problem with killing/closing winword processes I start this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191431/powershell-how-to-quit-or-close-not-kill-word-document-process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is remove the appropriate registry key(s):

HKUser:(SID)\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\(Office application)\Resiliency\DocumentRecovery